# “Bad Credentials” - Unable to sign in to Magento Marketplace via admin UI

Tags: extensions, marketplace, web-setup-wizard

I'm using Magento version 2.3.3 CE and until yesterday my account was linked with the marketplace.
Yesterday however when I entered the web setup it was asking again for my credentials and when inserting them it gave me "Bad credentials".

- I verified (several times) that it has no spaces before or after the keys;
- I tried to generate and insert new keys
- I even tried to make a new Magento Marketplace account andI still get "bad credentials"
  Suggestions on how to fix the problem please?

Comment: me neither, must be general problem.

Comment: Yes, I confirm the same issue since yesterday.. This is a "general" error affecting many users and I am trying to find a bug report on the Magento support forum, but nothing so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it was general, they pushed out a deployment. The keys are working again, I deleted the old keys and created new ones.

Comment: So what happens now? Is there a timeline (ETA) to resolve this issue? Is there a tracker to the status of this error? anybody else facing this issue? @Marcel are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @YacoubOweis yes mine are working now. You need to delete the old keys and create new keys